# firebase: simple request with where in subproperty

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i Want to make a simple request to verify a condition in my where

my example of object in firebase

```
{
  data: 'ezifzoeifh',
  value: {
    a: '1',
    b: '48'
  }
}
```

my request

```
firestore()
                .collection('database_test')
                .where("value.b", "==", 48)
                .get()
```

I try this but , it's not working. Maybe it's not possible ?
thanks for help:

Comment: What is the error or output that you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparisons in Firestore are type-specific. Your `b` value in the database is a string, so you have to also pass a string to `where:

```
.where("value.b", "==", '48')
```